# No values from group by / having query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, having

I'm trying to run a query in SQL Server to find title of the movie for those reviewers who rated more than one movies. Please check below query and the diagram.

```
SELECT [mov_id] FROM [dbo].[rating$] 
GROUP BY [mov_id]
HAVING COUNT ([rev_id])>1
```

[image]

The data for the table rating$ is as below:

```
mov_id | rev_id | rev_stars | num_o_ratings
--------+--------+-----------+---------------
    901 |   9001 |      8.40 |        263575
    902 |   9002 |      7.90 |         20207
    903 |   9003 |      8.30 |        202778
    906 |   9005 |      8.20 |        484746
    924 |   9006 |      7.30 |
    908 |   9007 |      8.60 |        779489
    909 |   9008 |           |        227235
    910 |   9009 |      3.00 |        195961
    911 |   9010 |      8.10 |        203875
    912 |   9011 |      8.40 |
    914 |   9013 |      7.00 |        862618
    915 |   9001 |      7.70 |        830095
    916 |   9014 |      4.00 |        642132
    925 |   9015 |      7.70 |         81328
    918 |   9016 |           |        580301
    920 |   9017 |      8.10 |        609451
    921 |   9018 |      8.00 |        667758
    922 |   9019 |      8.40 |        511613
    923 |   9020 |      6.70 |         13091
```

Currently I'm having no value in the result, whereas I should retrieve values as 901 and 915 as a values.
Anyone's help to understand the miss would be appreciated.

```
SELECT [mov_id] FROM [dbo].[rating$] 
GROUP BY [mov_id]
HAVING COUNT ([rev_id])>1
```

Comment: And as per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Hi @DaleK thanks much for your prompt responses, I'll consider all the points you mentioned going forward. 
I'm trying to find all the mov_id (which are unique in table 'rating$) for the specific the rev_id which exist more than one time in the same table. Please let me know if require any additional information.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion, @DaleK. I've updated the question and will consider your suggestion about DDL+DML data from the next question, I don't have it for this table at the moment.
Additionally, I would be very grateful if you could let me know a preferred resource to practice exercises on MSSQL especially on Joins & Subqueries.

Comment: Yes @DaleK, I've gone through the answer from that resource but noticed this while I was trying to figure out by myself hence posted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't query both things at the same time. So you can either use a sub-query to obtain the reviewers of interest. Or use a window function to work out which rows are valid e.g.

```
declare @Rating table (mov_id int, rev_id int, rev_stars decimal(9,2), num_of_ratings int);

insert into @Rating (mov_id, rev_id, rev_stars, num_of_ratings)
values
(901,9001,8.40,263575),
(902,9002,7.90,20207),
(903,9003,8.30,202778),
(906,9005,8.20,484746),
(924,9006,7.30,null),
(908,9007,8.60,779489),
(909,9008,null,227235),
(910,9009,3.00,195961),
(911,9010,8.10,203875),
(912,9011,8.40,null),
(914,9013,7.00,862618),
(915,9001,7.70,830095),
(916,9014,4.00,642132),
(925,9015,7.70,81328),
(918,9016,null,580301),
(920,9017,8.10,609451),
(921,9018,8.00,667758),
(922,9019,8.40,511613),
(923,9020,6.70,13091);

-- Approach 1: Using Subquery 
SELECT mov_id
FROM @Rating
WHERE rev_id IN (
    SELECT rev_id
    FROM @Rating
    GROUP BY rev_id
    HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
);

-- Approach 2: Using CTE + Window Function
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT mov_id, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rev_id) num_reviews
    FROM @Rating
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE num_reviews > 1;
```

Note 1: I created the DDL+DML from your data, so in future if you could do it please.

Note 2: Please don't use implicit (comma separated) joins as suggested by that link. They are far from best practice. Instead use proper joins.

Comment: This is crystal clear and very much helpful, Dale. Thanks much again, and I'll be considering each of your suggestions moving forward.

Comment: Dale, could you please help me with the question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328486/couldnt-get-result-from-group-by-having-query