# couldn't get result from group by- having query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, syntax, having

I'm trying to find an year when maximum number of movies were published having genre "Mystery" with total count of movies. Correct answer is 2001 and 2 for this database.

Below is the DB script with records: (Tables to use: movie, movie_geners, geners)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[actor$](
    [act_id] [float] NULL,
    [act_fname] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [act_lname] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [act_gender] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[director$]    Script Date: 4/30/2021 10:26:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[director$](
    [dir_id] [float] NULL,
    [dir_fname] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [dir_lname] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[genres$]    Script Date: 4/30/2021 10:26:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[genres$](
    [gen_id] [float] NULL,
    [gen_title] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[movie$]    Script Date: 4/30/2021 10:26:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[movie$](
    [mov_id] [float] NULL,
    [mov_title] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [mov_year] [float] NULL,
    [mov_time] [float] NULL,
    [mov_lang] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [mov_dt_rel] [datetime] NULL,
    [mov_rel_country] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[movie_cast$]    Script Date: 4/30/2021 10:26:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[movie_cast$](
    [act_id] [float] NULL,
    [mov_id] [float] NULL,
    [role] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[movie_direction$]    Script Date: 4/30/2021 10:26:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[movie_direction$](
    [dir_id] [float] NULL,
    [mov_id] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[movie_genres$]    Script Date: 4/30/2021 10:26:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[movie_genres$](
    [mov_id] [float] NULL,
    [gen_id] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[rating$]    Script Date: 4/30/2021 10:26:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[rating$](
    [mov_id] [float] NULL,
    [rev_id] [float] NULL,
    [rev_stars] [float] NULL,
    [num_o_ratings] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[reviewer$]    Script Date: 4/30/2021 10:26:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[reviewer$](
    [rev_id] [float] NULL,
    [rev_name] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (101, N'James', N'Stewart', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (102, N'Deborah', N'Kerr', N'F')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (103, N'Peter', N'OToole', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (104, N'Robert', N'De Niro', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (105, N'F. Murray', N'Abraham', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (106, N'Harrison', N'Ford', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (107, N'Nicole', N'Kidman', N'F')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (108, N'Stephen', N'Baldwin', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (109, N'Jack', N'Nicholson', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (110, N'Mark', N'Wahlberg', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (111, N'Woody', N'Allen', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (112, N'Claire', N'Danes', N'F')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (113, N'Tim', N'Robbins', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (114, N'Kevin', N'Spacey', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (115, N'Kate', N'Winslet', N'F')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (116, N'Robin', N'Williams', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (117, N'Jon', N'Voight', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (118, N'Ewan', N'McGregor', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (119, N'Christian', N'Bale', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (120, N'Maggie', N'Gyllenhaal', N'F')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (121, N'Dev', N'Patel', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (122, N'Sigourney', N'Weaver', N'F')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (123, N'David', N'Aston', N'M')
INSERT [dbo].[actor$] ([act_id], [act_fname], [act_lname], [act_gender]) VALUES (124, N'Ali', N'Astin', N'F')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (201, N'Alfred', N'Hitchcock')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (202, N'Jack', N'Clayton')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (203, N'David', N'Lean')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (204, N'Michael', N'Cimino')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (205, N'Milos', N'Forman')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (206, N'Ridley', N'Scott')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (207, N'Stanley', N'Kubrick')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (208, N'Bryan', N'Singer')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (209, N'Roman', N'Polanski')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (210, N'Paul', N'Thomas Anderson')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (211, N'Woody', N'Allen')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (212, N'Hayao', N'Miyazaki')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (213, N'Frank', N'Darabont')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (214, N'Sam', N'Mendes')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (215, N'James', N'Cameron')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (216, N'Gus', N'Van Sant')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (217, N'John', N'Boorman')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (218, N'Danny', N'Boyle')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (219, N'Christopher', N'Nolan')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (220, N'Richard', N'Kelly')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (221, N'Kevin', N'Spacey')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (222, N'Andrei', N'Tarkovsky')
INSERT [dbo].[director$] ([dir_id], [dir_fname], [dir_lname]) VALUES (223, N'Peter', N'Jackson')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1001, N'Action')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1002, N'Adventure')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1003, N'Animation')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1004, N'Biography')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1005, N'Comedy')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1006, N'Crime')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1007, N'Drama')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1008, N'Horror')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1009, N'Music')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1010, N'Mystery')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1011, N'Romance')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1012, N'Thriller')
INSERT [dbo].[genres$] ([gen_id], [gen_title]) VALUES (1013, N'War')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (901, N'Vertigo', 1958, 128, N'English', CAST(N'1958-08-24T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (902, N'The Innocents', 1961, 100, N'English', CAST(N'1962-02-19T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'SW')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (903, N'Lawrence of Arabia', 1962, 216, N'English', CAST(N'1962-12-11T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (904, N'The Deer Hunter', 1978, 183, N'English', CAST(N'1979-03-08T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (905, N'Amadeus', 1984, 160, N'English', CAST(N'1985-01-07T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (906, N'Blade Runner', 1982, 117, N'English', CAST(N'1982-09-09T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (907, N'Eyes Wide Shut', 1999, 159, N'English', NULL, N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (908, N'The Usual Suspects', 1995, 106, N'English', CAST(N'1995-08-25T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (909, N'Chinatown', 1974, 130, N'English', CAST(N'1974-08-09T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (910, N'Boogie Nights', 1997, 155, N'English', CAST(N'1998-02-16T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (911, N'Annie Hall', 1977, 93, N'English', CAST(N'1977-04-20T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'USA')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (912, N'Princess Mononoke', 1997, 134, N'Japanese', CAST(N'2001-10-19T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (913, N'The Shawshank Redemption', 1994, 142, N'English', CAST(N'1995-02-17T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (914, N'American Beauty', 1999, 122, N'English', NULL, N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (915, N'Titanic', 1997, 194, N'English', CAST(N'1998-01-23T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (916, N'Good Will Hunting', 1997, 126, N'English', CAST(N'1998-06-03T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (917, N'Deliverance', 1972, 109, N'English', CAST(N'1982-10-05T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (918, N'Trainspotting', 1996, 94, N'English', CAST(N'1996-02-23T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (919, N'The Prestige', 2006, 130, N'English', CAST(N'2006-11-10T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (920, N'Donnie Darko', 2001, 113, N'English', NULL, N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (921, N'Slumdog Millionaire', 2008, 120, N'English', CAST(N'2009-01-09T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (922, N'Aliens', 1986, 137, N'English', CAST(N'1986-08-29T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (923, N'Beyond the Sea', 2004, 118, N'English', CAST(N'2004-11-26T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (924, N'Avatar', 2009, 162, N'English', CAST(N'2009-12-17T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (926, N'Seven Samurai', 1954, 207, N'Japanese', CAST(N'1954-04-26T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'JP')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (927, N'Spirited Away', 2001, 125, N'Japanese', CAST(N'2003-09-12T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (928, N'Back to the Future', 1985, 116, N'English', CAST(N'1985-12-04T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (925, N'Braveheart', 1995, 178, N'English', CAST(N'1995-09-08T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'UK')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (100, N'Bollywood', 1993, 93, N'Hindi', CAST(N'2021-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'India')
INSERT [dbo].[movie$] ([mov_id], [mov_title], [mov_year], [mov_time], [mov_lang], [mov_dt_rel], [mov_rel_country]) VALUES (101, N'A 2001 Movie', 2001, 150, N'English', CAST(N'2001-09-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'USA')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (101, 901, N'John Scottie Ferguson')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (102, 902, N'Miss Giddens')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (103, 903, N'T.E. Lawrence')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (104, 904, N'Michael')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (105, 905, N'Antonio Salieri')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (106, 906, N'Rick Deckard')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (107, 907, N'Alice Harford')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (108, 908, N'McManus')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (110, 910, N'Eddie Adams')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (111, 911, N'Alvy Singer')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (112, 912, N'San')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (113, 913, N'Andy Dufresne')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (114, 914, N'Lester Burnham')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (115, 915, N'Rose DeWitt Bukater')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (116, 916, N'Sean Maguire')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (117, 917, N'Ed')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (118, 918, N'Renton')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (120, 920, N'Elizabeth Darko')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (121, 921, N'Older Jamal')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (122, 922, N'Ripley')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (114, 923, N'Bobby Darin')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (109, 909, N'J.J. Gittes')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_cast$] ([act_id], [mov_id], [role]) VALUES (119, 919, N'Alfred Borden')
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (201, 901)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (202, 902)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (203, 903)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (204, 904)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (205, 905)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (206, 906)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (207, 907)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (208, 908)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (209, 909)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (210, 910)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (211, 911)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (212, 912)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (213, 913)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (214, 914)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (215, 915)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (216, 916)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (217, 917)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (218, 918)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (219, 919)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (220, 920)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (218, 921)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (215, 922)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_direction$] ([dir_id], [mov_id]) VALUES (221, 923)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (922, 1001)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (917, 1002)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (903, 1002)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (912, 1003)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (911, 1005)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (908, 1006)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (913, 1006)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (926, 1007)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (928, 1007)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (918, 1007)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (921, 1007)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (902, 1008)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (923, 1009)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (907, 1010)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (927, 1010)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (901, 1010)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (914, 1011)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (906, 1012)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (904, 1013)
INSERT [dbo].[movie_genres$] ([mov_id], [gen_id]) VALUES (101, 1010)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (901, 9001, 8.4, 263575)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (902, 9002, 7.9, 20207)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (903, 9003, 8.3, 202778)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (906, 9005, 8.2, 484746)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (924, 9006, 7.3, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (908, 9007, 8.6, 779489)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (909, 9008, NULL, 227235)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (910, 9009, 3, 195961)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (911, 9010, 8.1, 203875)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (912, 9011, 8.4, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (914, 9013, 7, 862618)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (915, 9001, 7.7, 830095)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (916, 9014, 4, 642132)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (925, 9015, 7.7, 81328)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (918, 9016, NULL, 580301)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (920, 9017, 8.1, 609451)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (921, 9018, 8, 667758)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (922, 9019, 8.4, 511613)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (923, 9020, 6.7, 13091)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (101, 9001, 9, 50000)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (927, 9001, 8, 45000)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (920, 9001, 7, 46000)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (907, 9001, 9, 50000)
INSERT [dbo].[rating$] ([mov_id], [rev_id], [rev_stars], [num_o_ratings]) VALUES (914, 9001, 7, 45000)
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9001, N'Righty Sock')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9002, N'Jack Malvern')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9003, N'Flagrant Baronessa')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9004, N'Alec Shaw')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9005, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9006, N'Victor Woeltjen')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9007, N'Simon Wright')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9008, N'Neal Wruck')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9009, N'Paul Monks')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9010, N'Mike Salvati')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9011, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9012, N'Wesley S. Walker')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9013, N'Sasha Goldshtein')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9014, N'Josh Cates')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9015, N'Krug Stillo')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9016, N'Scott LeBrun')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9017, N'Hannah Steele')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9018, N'Vincent Cadena')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9019, N'Brandt Sponseller')
INSERT [dbo].[reviewer$] ([rev_id], [rev_name]) VALUES (9020, N'Richard Adams')
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [movie] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
```

Below is the query I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT
    movie.mov_year, COUNT(movie.mov_year) AS 'total_movies'
FROM 
    movie$ movie 
JOIN 
    movie_genres$ m_geners ON m_geners.mov_id = movie.mov_id
JOIN 
    genres$ geners ON geners.gen_id = m_geners.gen_id
                   AND geners.gen_title LIKE '%mystery%'
GROUP BY 
    movie.mov_year
HAVING 
    movie.mov_year IN
       (SELECT 
            mov_year mov_yr 
        FROM 
            movie$ m 
        GROUP BY 
            mov_year
        HAVING 
            COUNT([mov_year]) = 
               (SELECT 
                    MAX(a.movie_count) maxcount 
                FROM 
                   (SELECT 
                        COUNT([dbo].[movie$].[mov_year]) movie_count 
                    FROM 
                        [dbo].[movie$] 
                    GROUP BY 
                        movie$.mov_year
                    ) AS a
               ) 
        )
```

I'm getting no result from this.
Please suggest what update I should make in the query.

Comment: I recommend shorter table aliases, they are intended to make your query clearer. Personally I would alias Movies as M, Genres as G and MovieGenres as MG. Also if you can ensure that you provide a [mre] with the emphasis on minimal. You have provided a huge amount of un-necessary data, which makes it harder to see the actual question. If you result only requires 3 tables, only show 3 tables.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK I deeply appreciate your guidance. The TOP WITH TIES worked.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do the job?

```
SELECT TOP(1) movie.mov_year, COUNT(movie.mov_year) AS 'total_movies'
FROM 
    movie$ movie 
    JOIN movie_genres$ m_geners ON m_geners.mov_id = movie.mov_id
    JOIN genres$ geners ON geners.gen_id = m_geners.gen_id
WHERE geners.gen_title LIKE '%mystery%'
GROUP BY movie.mov_year
ORDER BY COUNT(movie.mov_year) desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, Warren. This query works when there is only one year to which count of movies is max. If there are more than one years having same number of maximum movies, I may not use TOP as i would like to have result for all the years which are having same max number of movies produced of same genre. Any further suggestions, please?

Comment: @Deva I encourage you to spend some time doing your own research in addition to asking for assistance here. In this particular case, reading the [documentation for TOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) shows that there is an argument `WITH TIES` which, as the name suggests, shows multiple rows when they have the same value.

Comment: @Deva you could always update this answer since it put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve the result with TOP WITH TIES as suggested by Dale K.
Below is the query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES mov_count,mov_year,rev_stars AS avg_rev_stars
FROM
( 
    SELECT  COUNT(m.mov_year) mov_count,    m.mov_year
            ,AVG(ISNULL(r.rev_stars,0)) rev_stars
    FROM movie$ m
    INNER JOIN movie_genres$ mg on m.mov_id=mg.mov_id
    INNER JOIN genres$ g on mg.gen_id=g.gen_id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.rating$ r on m.mov_id = r.mov_id
    GROUP BY m.mov_year, gen_title
    HAVING gen_title='Mystery'
) AS t1
ORDER BY t1.mov_count desc
```

Result:

[image]